# Conexion modulo WIFI a ANDROID

Tags: android

En mi empresa están pensando en trabajar a través de aplicaciones Android con diferentes dispositivos mediante WIFI. En mi caso, mi labor seria encargarme de la parte de Android, la programación de los dispositivos corresponderá a alguien mas.

Para hacer las pruebas, el modulo WIFI seleccionado es el de esta placa:

[ATSAMW25-XPRO](http://www.atmel.com/tools/ATSAMW25-XPRO.aspx)

Hasta ahora no había trabajado con dispositivos externos, la idea que llevo en mente seria conectar la placa por puerto serie a mi PC y desde el móvil mandar una cadena estilo "hola mundo" que recibiría por en el PC. 
(Básicamente esa es mi labor, enviar cadenas y que el modulo las pase a un micro).

¿Alguna sugerencia de por donde empezar? ¿Algún código de ejemplo para poder conectar con el Dispositivo?

Un saludo y gracias por adelantado.

Answer (score 1):

Revisa la guía de desarrollo del sitio http://www.atmel.com/, no se si esperabas programar en Java, pero tienes que realizarlo en C.

En la guía viene un ejemplo para interactuar con Android a travez del board SAMW25 :

1)Inicializar el módulo socket y crea un socket del servidor TCP.

```
addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
addr.sin_port = _htons((MAIN_WIFI_M2M_SERVER_PORT));
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
socketInit();
registerSocketCallback(socket_cb, NULL);
...
while (1) {
m2m_wifi_handle_events(NULL);
if (tcp_server_socket < 0) {
/* Open TCP server socket */
if ((tcp_server_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0))
```

Activa el modo de AP antes del bucle principal. (Consulte la sección "How to Run AP Mode" ejemplo):

```
ret = m2m_wifi_enable_ap(&strM2MAPConfig);
```

Después de conectar tu dispositivo  a la SAM W25 envía configuración del AP, desactiva el modo AP conecta el AP con la información dada.

```
static void socket_cb(SOCKET sock, uint8_t u8Msg, void *pvMsg)
{
case SOCKET_MSG_RECV:
m2m_wifi_disable_ap();
nm_bsp_sleep(500);
m2m_wifi_connect((char *)str_ssid, …
```

2) Construir el programa y descargarlo en la placa.

3) Iniciar la aplicación.

Si deseas usar notificaciones tienes que obtener la API key de  http://www.notifymyandroid.com/

**[Guía de programación para SAMW25](http://www.atmel.com/images/atmel-42437-software-programming-guide-for-sam-w25-xplained-pro_userguide.pdf)**

Comment: Hola Elena, en primer lugar muchas gracias por tu respuesta, aunque me he perdido un poco... estos ejemplos que me sugieres son para la placa, aunque por mi parte me gustaria saber desde android como comunicar con ella...a eso me referia, disculpa si no he sabido explicarme antes.

Comment: de Android hacia tu placa, lo haces con sockets https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/Socket.html
Ambos deben estar a la misma red, obitenes la dirección ip de la placa que seria el "host"